# Binomial or not Binomial?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I am looking at the following problem:

Let $C$ and $C'$ be two circles centered at $(0,0)$ such that $C'$ is inside $C$. Denote by "$+$" samples drawn from inside $C$ and "$-$" samples drawn from outside $C$. The probability of "$+$" samples falling in the gap between $C$ and $C'$ is $\delta$ (the distribution is unknown). We sample a total of $m$ samples from inside $C$ (i.e., supposed to be all "$+$").

If one "+" sample is mistakenly flipped into a "-" sample (it is unknown which sample, but there's definitely one), then (according to my calculations):

$$\Pr[\text{no “$+$” samples fall in } \delta\text{-gap}] \leq (1-\delta)^{m-1}$$

However, someone else insists it should be:

$$\Pr[\text{no “$+$” samples fall in } \delta\text{-gap}] = m(1-\delta)^{m-1} \delta  $$

Is it the latter? If it is, I cannot see why (and the other person was unable to explain their understanding besides insisting it is binomial).

Any insight would be much appreciated!

It might help to understand my reasoning -- it does not matter where the false "$-$" falls since it is not a "$+$", and I am only interested in where the "$+$" (as I perceive them, error included) fall.

**Here is how I derived mine:**

$$\Pr[\text{no “$+$” samples fall in } \delta\text{-gap } | \text{one mistake}] = \Pr[\cup_{i=1}^m \{i \text{ is a mistake }\cap \text{ rest not in } \delta\text{-gap }\} 
\leq \sum_{i=1}^m\Pr[\text{ rest not in } \delta\text{-gap }\ | i \text{ is a mistake }]\Pr[i \text{ is a mistake }] $$

where the last transition is by the union-bound.

Now, since the samples are iid we obtain:

$$\sum_{i=1}^m\Pr[\text{ rest not in } \delta\text{-gap }\ | i \text{ is a mistake }]\Pr[i \text{ is a mistake }] = m(1-\delta)^{m-1}\frac{1}{m} = (1-\delta)^{m-1}$$

So I see now mine is an upper bound due to the union-bound (note to readers of previous version - I had a "=" and a multiplication by $m$ before, which is now fixed).

Still - could it be possible to obtain the other person't equality using the Binomial distribution?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you are both wrong and the probability should be $(1-\delta)^{m-1}$. The problem is no different than if you only had $m-1$ samples to begin with (and they were all of the "+" type).

Comment: But if that doesn't convince you, consider that $m(1-\delta)^{m-1}$ can be larger than $1$ (for example, when $m=2$ and $\delta<\frac 12$). So your formula can't possibly be right.

Comment: @tuna the multiplication by $m$ stems from the fact that we don't know which of the $m$ samples is the rogue one - so in the Binomial case it is the $m\choose 1$. Still, I see now why mine is invalid, bu how did the other person reach the conclusion. Adding to my question how I derived mine to see if anyone can spot where I went wrong.

Comment: @tuna while spelling out my calculations I spotted a mistake (which still doesn't help explain the Bionmial result), that, when fixed, yields an upper bound of $(1-\delta)^{m-1}$ as you suggested.